# Coding an Interactive Game in Python Using Turtle: Hopper

Tags: python, pygame

I'd like to know how to code a certain portion of my game, Hopper. In this interactive python game using import turtle, I would like to create a turtle the user can control. I would like this turtle to jump when the spacebar is used, for the purpose of the user being able to jump over objects that should consistently move towards the player's turtle from the right side of the screen.

My question is, how to I make a circle shaped turtle jump when I hit the space bar and fall back to the ground, so that it can jump again when the next obstacle comes?
How do I create a code for obstacles, AKA, rectanglular shaped turtles, to move towards the player's circle turtle for the player's circle turtle to jump over? Thank you so so much for your time and help, will upvote.

If possible, I would love to know how to display a "Game Over" message if the player is unsuccessful in jumping over one of the rectangle obstacle turtles with the circle turtle.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem in Software Engineering.  But let's take a step back.  How do you cook breakfast?   Well what's breakfast - let's say "boiled egg".  What's an egg? What is it to "boil"? What sort of egg? Where does it come from? How big is it?  Is it an [Emu egg](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Faea-emu.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F12%2Feggs-2.jpg&f=1&nofb=1)?  How long do you boil it for? Etc. Etc. Etctera.

A big question like "How to Make Hopper" is really a huge list of tiny tiny problems.  How do you draw on the screen, how to you read a key press, how do you move the turtle, how do I make that "sproinggg" sound when it jumps...

So.  Start at the beginning, ignore the "noise" of what you can't do, and concentrate on what you can do.  What's the simplest starting point?   Write down some notes, draw some screen-layouts.  Think about how it's all going to work.  What are the first steps now?

Here's some simple code that opens a window and reads the keyboard. Take this code, and adapt it to handle the user-input according to your design.

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 400
WINDOW_SURFACE  = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF
WINDOW_MAX_FPS  = 60

BACK_COLOUR = (   3,   5,  54)

### initialisation
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), WINDOW_SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Hopper")


### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle Window & Keyboard Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN ):
            if ( event.key == pygame.K_SPACE ):
                print( 'Space-key pushed' )
            elif ( event.key == pygame.K_j ):
                print( 'j pushed' )

    # Handle Key-states
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
        print("up")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
        print("down")

    # Update the window
    window.fill( BACK_COLOUR )
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick( WINDOW_MAX_FPS )
    
pygame.quit()
```

Next start with simple graphics - you don't need a graphic-artist drawn turtle-avatar at this stage, just a box.  Once you have this drawing, work on making it move, then make it move according to user-input.  Keep chipping away at the program, but heading towards your design.

Plenty of beginners here get stuck trying to implement a beautiful 50-frame player-walking animation as a first step, and get lost and disillusioned when it's not easy (or perfect).  Keep it simple, and actually finish your project.